# Как установить библиотеку payeer-api?

Tags: python, pip

При скачивании библиотеки с помощью pip выдаёт ошибку:

```
Collecting payeer-api
  Using cached payeer_api-0.1.tar.gz (3.3 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [8 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\Санамхон\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xby5bsvv\payeer-a
pi\setup.py", line 8, in <module>
          long_description=open(join(dirname(__file__), 'README.rst')).read(),
        File "c:\users\санамхон\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\encod
ings\cp1251.py", line 23, in decode
          return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
      UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 488
: character maps to <undefined>
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem wit
h pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> payeer-api

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

Как решить?

Comment: `санамхон` — видать, кириллица внутри пути не нравиться этому модулю.

Comment: вы можете объяснить по точнее

Comment: `C:\Users\Санамхон` — попробуйте обойтись без кириллицы внутри пути. так понятнее?

Comment: да попробую сейчас

Comment: а как это сделать? не пойму как

Comment: @Daler русский язык уберите. `Санамхон` переименуйте как-нибудь на английский язык

Comment: @Daler проще всего переустановить Python в корень диска, например, в папку `C:\Python38`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Посмотрите внимательней на путь установке, в имени вашего пользователя используются русские символы, замените имя пользователя на англисский буквы и библиотека корректно установится

Comment: другие библиотеки устанавливаются при таком пути

Comment: @Alpha, простое изменение имени пользователя и меняет автоматически имя папки пользователя. Только если нового пользователя создать с именем только с латинскими буквами. Но проще переустановить Python в другое место, например в  `C:\Python38`